# Boxing on assignment to ValueType?

Tags: c#

If I assign a simple value type (e.g. an int) to an attribute of type ValueType, is the value then boxed?

For example if I do this:

```
int i = 4;
ValueType test = i;
```

Will the value be boxed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will.  This is because each type occupies a constant amount of memory at runtime (`int` takes 4 bytes, for example).  A struct will take as much space is required to lay out all of the fields in memory.

Since you can store *any* value type in `ValueType`, and since `ValueType` would have to be exactly the same size as the type you're assigning to `test`, the `ValueType` type is actually a reference type.

Consider:

```
int a = 0;
long b = 1;

ValueType test;

test = a;
test = b;
```

This is perfectly valid code.  `test` must occupy a fixed size on the stack, and `a` and `b` are different sizes.  Hopefully this clarifies why exactly `ValueType` cannot itself be a value type.  (It's related to the reason why you can't derive value types.)

Comment: Good explanation of why `ValueType` is a reference type.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that will box it - [`ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) is a reference type (a class), confusingly enough :) It's simply the type from which every value type "inherits" (directly in the case of structs, and indirectly in the case of enums).

Boxing occurs any time you assign a value type value to a variable of a reference type, including `object`, `ValueType`, `Enum` and any interfaces. (It also occurs when use a value type value as an argument where the parameter is one of those types, etc.)

Comment: Glad i'm not the only one that finds it slightly confusing that ValueType is a reference type.  I understand why, but it still confused me briefly.

Comment: @Jon Then why `enums` are called value types though `Enum` is a class derived from `ValueType`

Comment: @Ashley: Because each enum type is separate, and *is* a value type - it's just that the type that each enum type "inherits" from is a reference type. It's just like `int` and `char` are both value types, but they "inherit" from `ValueType`. ("Inheritance" with value types is odd...)

Answer (score 0):

`ValueType` is a reference type. The IL generated on this assignment actually boxes the struct.

Here is an example of a box instruction when assigning to object:

```
void Main()
{
    object o = 1;

    Console.Write(o);
}

IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  box         System.Int32
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     
IL_0008:  call        System.Console.Write
```

And when assigning to `ValueType`:

```
void Main()
{
    ValueType o = 1;

    Console.Write(o);
}

IL_0000:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0001:  box         System.Int32
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     
IL_0008:  call        System.Console.Write
```